# Exclude option from select in nz-select in nz-zorro

Tags: angular, html-select, antd, ant-design-pro

I am working on one angular project in which I have install nz-zorro-ant-design package for Consistent UI Elements.

one Scenario :

I am using `NZ-Select` element from `Package`. as a requirement of a project, I am rendering multiple items as a option in that select box like this :

### Component.ts :

```
let heros = [ 
            { name: "Tony", id: 1, hasMoney: true },
            { name: "Bruce", id: 2, hasMoney: false},
            { name: "Sam", id: 3, hasMoney: false},
            { name: "Oliva", id: 4, hasMoney: true},
 ]
let selectedHero = null;

filterHerosList(query, option) {
      return option.nzLabel.toLowercase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) && !nzDisabled
}
```

### Component.html :

```
<nz-select [(ngModel)]="selectedHero" nzAllowClear nzPlaceHolder="Select hero" [nzFilterOption]="filterHerosList"> 
     <nz-option *ngFor="let hero of heros;" nzLabel="{{hero.name}}" [nzDisabled]="!hasMoney" nzValue="{{hero.id}}">
     </nz-option>
</nz-select>
```

### Dropdown's expected Behavior:

Dropdown's `select` and `search` behavior is like this. if hero has a money (hasMoney) then and only then it should be selectable.

### What I have tried :

1. I used `[nzFilterOption]` callback of nz-select for filter-out searched option list. So that User can't search for disabled option from list.
2. Disable options based on `hasMoney` key's value
3. These are working properly

### Problem :

1. Disabled Option will be by default selected when it is on first position on option list.

Does anyone guys know the solution for this  problem ?